# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: Dynamics CRM 9.0 Organization Service

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9

We just received an update to Dynamics CRM 9.0, but it seems like a get a unresolved reference when I try to programmatically access the Organization Service Endpoint.

The Uri I am using for this CRM online instance is https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxtest.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=9'.

Please let me know if anything has changed that I cannot use this endpoint anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the following blog article helps you. There are several different possibilities why this is happening, but with version 9, so are easily fixed:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nishantranaweblog/archive/2018/01/31/metadata-contains-a-reference-that-cannot-be-resolved-https-orgname-crm8-dynamics-com-xrmservices-2011-organization-svc-wsdl-amp-sdkversion-9-error-in-dynamics-365

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

2011 aka soap endpoints are [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281891.aspx#Microsoft%20Dynamics%20CRM%202011%20endpoint), which means will be retired anytime. So you don’t have much time, earlier is better to convert to Web Api.

> Beginning with the Dynamics 365 (8.0) release, a new OData 4 endpoint was added to the Dynamics 365 application stack. This endpoint is known as the Web API. The Web API provides a development experience that can be used across a wide variety of programming languages, platforms, and devices. **The Web API is intended to replace the CRM 2011 endpoint, also known as the SOAP endpoint, for accessing the Dynamics 365 organization web service and other provided web services**.
>
> As of the release of Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Update 1 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Service Pack 1 (8.1.0), the CRM 2011 endpoint has been deprecated. **The 2011 endpoint will be removed some time after the release of Dynamics 365 version 9**. We plan to provide updates to the Dynamics 365 SDK assemblies and tools over the next several minor releases, retargeting them to use the Web API instead of the 2011 endpoint.

Till then check if [TLS 1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051700) is the issue like discussed [here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/266382).

Comment: We use Execute Multiple response which gives us good performance, hence we haven't switched the Web API. I know Web has a batch mode but i guess the performance isn't the same.

Answer (score 0):

The OData URL is

`https://[ORGNAME].crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/[EntitySet]`

The Organization URL is

`https://[ORGNAME].api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc`

(Double check the info by going under Settings -> Customizations -> Developer Resources)

Answer (score 0):

Check, please, that option "Don't use proxy server for local (intranet) address" off on Proxy tab in Network settings